# É possivel no GeckoFX do VB.net utilizar o `GetelementByID`?

Tags: vb.net

É possivel no GeckoFX do VB.net utilizar o `GetelementByID`? Fiz algumas tentativas com o código usando o google.com:

```
geckowebbrowser1.document.getelementbyid("lst-ib").setattribute("value", "teste")
```

porém está me retornando: "Referencia de objeto não definida para uma instancia de um objeto." Gecko.GeckoDomDocument.GetelementByID(...) retornou Nothing

Estou a alguns dias pesquisando e não encontrei.

Comment: Seria legal você formular melhor a pergunta. Dá uma lida no https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve pra ter uma ideia melhor

Answer (score 0):

Diferente do `WebBrowser`, é outro procedimento para obter o ID de um elemento em HTML. Considere esse pequeno código sua página e seu elemento:

```
<div id="lst-ib">conteúdo</div>
```

Na API do Gecko, você precisa criar uma instância de um `GeckoHtmlElement`, assim não irá causar referências nulas, como no seu erro.

```
Dim elemento As GeckoHtmlElement
ele = geckowebbrowser1.Document.GetHtmlElementById("lst-ib")
If(ele Is Nothing) MsgBox("Não foi possível encontrar um elemento com esse ID.")
ele.setAttribute("value", "teste")
```

---

[Documentação do setAttribute(string, string)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

[Fonte da resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534174/geckofx-get-gethtmlelementbyid)

Comment: Agradeço sua resposta, porem não consegui usar o exemplo que me falou.
continuo com o mesmo retorno nulo.
"Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

Comment: Estranho. Pode deixar claro a linha que acontece o erro?

Comment: Private Sub btnenviar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnenviar.Click 
 
  Dim ele As Gecko.GeckoHtmlElement ele = wb01.Document.GetHtmlElementById("lst-ib")  
  
ele.SetAttribute("value", "teste")"ao inserir nesta linha me retorna Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."   

End Sub 

desculpe não consegui formatar o Script na pagina

Comment: Reformulei a resposta com uma "pista". Tente executar agora e me atualize aqui.

Comment: no google, executou a MsgBox e não  inseriu dando o mesmo erro.  

mais uma pequena dúvida!!

Comment: é possível inserir dados usando GetElementsByClassName ?

Comment: Não achei documentação sobre `GetElementsByClassName`. Veja sua declaração e se há métodos para inserção de dados na função.